# Can anyone explain this code to me in plain english?

Tags: java

output is 142963

```
int i, j, ans;
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{ 
for (j = i; j > 0; j--)
{
    ans = i * j;
    System.out.print(ans);
}
System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: You should at least tag this with the relevant language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used javascript and I do not get the same output.

```js
var i, j, ans; 

for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) { 
  for (j = i; j > 0; j--) { 
    ans = i * j; 
    console.log(ans, i, j)
    document.body.innerHTML += ans + "</br>"
  }

}
```

**EDIT**

Attempt at plain english. There are two loops, one nested in the other. The outer loop is counting up from 1 to 3. Each iteration `i` is incremented by 1 (`i++`). The inner loop starts with the the value of `i` from the parent iteration and counts down to 1.

outer iteration 1: i = 1; j = 1; 1*1=1; answer = 1

outer iteration 2: i = 2; j = 2; 2*2=4; answer = 4

inner iteration 1: i = 2; j = 1; 1*2=2; answer = 2

outer iteration 3: i = 3; j = 3; 3*3=9; answer = 9

inner iteration 1: i = 3; j = 2; 3*2=6; answer = 6

inner iteration 2: i = 3; j = 1; 3*1=3; answer = 3

Comment: Apart from the fact you've added an extra `<br/>`, which isn't in the original code, the outputs are identical.

Comment: I believe the original post said the output was "1,2,3"

Comment: That explains it, the question went through several edits in quick succession.

Answer (score 1):

It computes `i*j` where `1<= i <= 3` and `0 < j <= i`.
So it computes and prints:
`1*1
2*2
2*1
3*3
3*2
3*1`